# fatal error - cannot connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple php blog and downloaded demo files from here - https://daveismyname.com/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php-bp.

Creating database (named `blog01`) and tables was sucessful.

On index.php I have an error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message ' in D:\localhost\blog-01\includes\config.php on line 11`

config.php:

```
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','username');
define('DBPASS','password');
define('DBNAME','blog01');

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I tried all combinations of username and password (demo, admin...) without success.

Also tried without `port=8889`.

php version - 5.6.14

Any help.

Comment: So line 11 in `config.php` is `$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);` ?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be 11 lines in `config.php`

Comment: Does your server really listen on port 8889 ? Standard port is 3306 for MySQL. Wrong port generates an error

Comment: @Zimmi, I wrote - I tried without `port=8889`

Comment: @AlonEitan, yes that is line 11

Comment: @bonaca So Perry's answer should be accepted - Now you are able to see that you're using an incorrect username\password and only you can know what those are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a try and a catch to see the message of the [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
   exit;
}
```

The port is only needed when the port is not the same as the default port (3306 for mysql)

If that is the case then the connection is:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Comment: Perry, now I have this - `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'Admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: @bonaca Ok, that means that the username and/or password is incorrect. You should check if the user you want to use exists and the password belongs to the user. Do you have phpmyadmin installed? That is an easy way to verify and if is not correct you can change or add a new user to your mysql

Comment: I check the table `blog-members`. There is only one user, named `Admin` and password is `$2y$10$wJxa1Wm0rtS2BzqKnoCPd.7QQzgu7D/aLlMR5Aw3O.m9jx3oRJ5R2`. How can I know the real password?

Comment: No you don't need that user name because that is for your application, you need the user name of mysql, I guess you will have a root user. so you could use that account if it is only on your local machine for learning. You can also add a user to mysql. If you use phpmyadmin, you can use the username and password you use then to login.

Comment: Perry, if I understand you well, I need username and password of phpMyAdmin ? I tried with user `root` without any password and I'm redirected form index.php to admin/login.php, with a login form. Here I tried various combinations - root, admin, demo... without sucess. I'm sure that I never set any password for phpMyAdmin.

Comment: phpmyadmin is just a tool and use mysql Users for authentication. What kind of OS are you using, so I can help you

Comment: I'm using win 7. Suddenly login is sucessful now, but I'm not sure where was the point. Anyway, I wil explore the whole procedure again. You already helped me a lot, thanks so much for your patiente. Let's say - solved.